# Le droit d’être + conjugaison du participe passé

Tags: grammaire

> les personnes en double diplôme ont le droit d’être exemptées de …

Ou

> les personnes en double diplôme ont le droit d’être exempté de …

Faut-il faire l’accord ? J’ai du mal à savoir.

Comment: C'est un accord avec le verbe être, ce sont les personnes qui sont exempt**ées**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le groupe de mot à considérer n'est pas « le droit d'être » mais « avoir le droit ». « Être » fait partie du groupe « être exempté ». « Avoir le droit de » c'est « avoir la possibilité de », c'est à dire « pouvoir ». Remplacer « avoir le droit » par « pouvoir » te permet de mieux voir le sujet de « être exempté » :

> **Les personnes** en double diplôme peuvent être exempt**ées** de...

Tu peux aussi repenser la phrase différemment :

- Il existe des personnes en double diplôme.
- Ces personnes ont un droit.
- Il existe des possibilités d'être exempté.
- Être en double diplôme est un des cas où des personnes sont exemptées.

Le sujet d'« être exempté » est « les personnes », l'accord se faisant avec le sujet, on écrit :

> **les personnes** en double diplôme ont le droit d’être exempt**ées** de...